# How do i get a Function to return a string value?

Tags: .net, vb.net, function

I'm working on another school project and I'm learning about creating a `Function`. In this example, I need to create a `Function` that will list out my 'Top Donors' who are manually entered in by me. The error I'm running into is I've created my `Function`, but at the end as I try and end it with `Return String`, I'm getting a syntax error and I'm not sure what I need to put after it.

```
Public Class Form1
    Function GetTopDonors() As String
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        sb.Append("Frank, $1,000,000")
        sb.Append("Joe, $980,000")
        Return String
    End Function

    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
        Dim TopDonors As String = GetTopDonors()
        txtDonorList.Text = TopDonors
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

Comment: You should do this by your own. The problem is evident; if you would have spent half of the time you did on posting this question in coming up with a solution, you would have already solved it.

Comment: Start with reading the error message produced when you compile. What does it read?

Comment: I agree with @varocarbas, also I think that you shouldn't start messing around with WinForms before you have a good understanding of the fundamentals of the language and the concept of OOP programming, I recommend you to practice some more with the console and get a better understanding on the matter. Good luck

Comment: The problem was NOT evident to me....seeing as why I asked for help in which I got lots of VERY educated answers and learned a lot. Rather then staring at my screen for 30 min because I don't know what to do. Thank you for taking the time to help me. ;)

Comment: If you are learning something, logically, not too many things are evident. What I meant was that this specific problem was more or less easily solvable by bearing in mind that it is part of the basic structure of a function (what you want to accomplish with it: returning the value you calculated or a blank string with no meaning?). I haven't been rude (not my intention, at least) just helpful: do some effort by your own and you would learn much more. But well... if you prefer the asking-by-default option, it is completely up to you.

Comment: (I thought that SO was not meant for doing homework; also I thought that it was expected from the OPs to do some effort by their own and have a minimum understanding. But apparently I was wrong (or this question actually hides a serious problem I cannot see); votes and participation never lie -> really popular and thus adequate question. I apologise to the OP and to the community for having wrongly voted to close it.)

Comment: @varocarbas Homework questions are not discouraged.  Asking SO to do your homework for you is obviously unwelcome, but if they have put effort into it and are legitimately stuck with an honest question, then typically people are willing to help.  It's admittedly a gray area.  We are all about helping each other learn.  Granted, this is a very simple, basic question, but for a beginner, it's not easily solvable on their own because they don't even know enough to even know what to search for to find the solution.

Comment: @StevenDoggart I do agree on the fact that when you start something, you get stuck pretty easily. But I think that there are different levels. Example: Dim temp As Date = "1-1-2011" -> why I get an error? It is quite in the limit but well... might not be fixed easily by an unexperienced person. But what was asked here is "why I get nothing when I return nothing?"; what sounds to me as something solvable by doing an effort by your own. But this is just how I see things; despite the sarcasm I do accept the opinion of the community, which is pretty clear here.

Comment: Again, thank you all for your help. I truly am trying to learn this and I truly do WANT to get better. I was just stuck. I didn't need the exact answer but guidance as to where to even start. I do appreciate everybody's time as simple or stupid as the question may seem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `StringBuilder.ToString()` method to get the string from builder.

```
Function GetTopDonors() As String
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

    sb.Append("Frank, $1,000,000")
    sb.Append("Joe, $980,000")

    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

Answer (score 5):

Change it to read: `Return sb.ToString()` and it should work for you.  That will return the String value of the StringBuilder which is what you want since the function returns a String.
`String` by itself is a type so you can't return it - you have to return an instance of it.

Make sense?

Comment: +1 as you replied first, although I think you could have mentioned using [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6730bwt.aspx) to get VS to point out problems like that.

Answer (score 3):

`String` is a **Type**, not a variable, so it doesn't make sense to `Return String`.  You need to return the value of a variable, not a type of a variable.  So, while you cannot `Return String`, you can, for instance, return any variable that *is* a string, like this:

```
Function GetTopDonors() As String
    Dim x As String
    Return x
End Function
```

In your case, you are using a `StringBuilder`, which isn't actually a `String`, but it can be converted to a `String` by calling the `ToString` method, like this:

```
Function GetTopDonors() As String
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("Frank, $1,000,000")
    sb.Append("Joe, $980,000")
    Dim myString As String = sb.ToString()
    Return myString
End Function
```

Or, you can skip creating the `myString` variable and just return the converted value directly, like this:

```
Function GetTopDonors() As String
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("Frank, $1,000,000")
    sb.Append("Joe, $980,000")
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

You'll find out soon enough, but I should also mention that you probably want `AppendLine` rather than `Append`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to return the string value of the `StringBuilder` (`sb`) you have to call `ToString` on it which will return the string value.

```
Return sb.ToString()
```